# Parsing Compound Coordinate Systems from file

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal

I'm trying to programmatically extract the coordinate system, preferably in EPSG code(s), from a series of files some of which have a compound coordinate reference system. I've noticed that when I drag the file in QGIS it properly extracts the coordinate system so I know it can be done. I've tried a few things to no success, I've included the code to things I've attempted

```py
from geomet import wkt as geomet_wkt
from shapely import wkt as shapely_wkt
from osgeo import gdal, osr


ds = gdal.Open(filepath)
wkt=ds.GetProjection()
json_wkt = geomet_wkt.loads(wkt)  # Value Error: Unsupported geometry type 'COMPD_CS'
json_wkt = shapely_wkt.loads(wkt) # WKTReading Error: Could not create geometry because of errors while reading input.

crs = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=wkt)
crs.AutoIdentifyEPSG()
crs.GetAuthorityCode(None) # returns None
```

[Link download file](https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/NH_Coastal_2019_B19/NH_Coastal_1_2019/TIFF/USGS_OPR_NH_Coastal_2019_B19_02751100.tif)

WKT of file extracted using `gdalsrsinfo`

```
COMPOUNDCRS["NAD83(2011) / New Hampshire (ftUS) + NAVD88 height (ftUS) - Geoid12B (ftUS)",
PROJCRS["NAD83(2011) / New Hampshire (ftUS)",
    BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83(2011)",
        DATUM["NAD83 (National Spatial Reference System 2011)",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",6318]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",42.5,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-71.6666666666667,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.999966667,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",984250,
            LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219]],
    ID["EPSG",6525]],
VERTCRS["NAVD88 height (ftUS)",
    VDATUM["North American Vertical Datum 1988"],
    CS[vertical,1],
        AXIS["gravity-related height",up,
            LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219]],
    ID["EPSG",6360]]]
```

Comment: The functions you are trying to use are for geometry in WKT form, not for coordinate system definitions in WKT form.

Comment: @bugmenot123 good point, maybe it deserves its own answer with the correct functions for reading WKT strings to CRS?

Comment: That would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too. Most python tools don't handle `COMPD_CS` / `COMPOUNDCRS` WKT strings well. The solution I found is to use [`pyproj`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/):

```py
from pyproj import CRS

# WKT from OP (whitespace removed for brevity):
wkt = '''COMPOUNDCRS["NAD83(2011) / New Hampshire (ftUS) + NAVD88 height (ftUS) - Geoid12B (ftUS)",PROJCRS["NAD83(2011) / New Hampshire (ftUS)",BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83(2011)",DATUM["NAD83 (National Spatial Reference System 2011)",ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],ID["EPSG",6318]],CONVERSION["unnamed",METHOD["Transverse Mercator",ID["EPSG",9807]],PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",42.5,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8801]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-71.6666666666667,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8802]],PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.999966667,SCALEUNIT["unity",1],ID["EPSG",8805]],PARAMETER["False easting",984250,LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],ID["EPSG",8806]],PARAMETER["False northing",0,LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],ID["EPSG",8807]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["easting",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219]],AXIS["northing",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219]],ID["EPSG",6525]],VERTCRS["NAVD88 height (ftUS)",VDATUM["North American Vertical Datum 1988"],CS[vertical,1],AXIS["gravity-related height",up,LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219]],ID["EPSG",6360]]]'''

crs = CRS.from_wkt(wkt)
```

Terminal output showing that `pyproj` recognizes both systems (`NAD83(2011) NH (ftUS)` and `NAVD88` tidal model height) together:

```
>>> crs
<Compound CRS: COMPOUNDCRS["NAD83(2011) / New Hampshire (ftUS) +  ...">
Name: NAD83(2011) / New Hampshire (ftUS) + NAVD88 height (ftUS) - Geoid12B (ftUS)
Axis Info [cartesian|vertical]:
- [east]: Easting (US survey foot)
- [north]: Northing (US survey foot)
- [up]: Gravity-related height (US survey foot)
Area of Use:
- undefined
Datum: NAD83 (National Spatial Reference System 2011)
- Ellipsoid: GRS 1980
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
Sub CRS:
- NAD83(2011) / New Hampshire (ftUS)
- NAVD88 height (ftUS)
>>> crs.name
'NAD83(2011) / New Hampshire (ftUS) + NAVD88 height (ftUS) - Geoid12B (ftUS)'
```

`pyproj` compound CRS objects have useful functionality like returning subscriptable lists of sub CRS which you can extract EPSG codes from (see [docs for `pyproj.crs.CRS`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/crs/crs.html#pyproj.crs.CRS)):

```
>>> crs.is_compound
True
>>> crs.sub_crs_list[0].to_epsg()
6525
>>> crs.sub_crs_list[1].to_epsg()
6360
```

Additionally, you can test whether those `list`ed CRS are vertical, which was helpful in my case, so may or may not be useful to you:

```
>>> crs.sub_crs_list[0].is_vertical
False
>>> crs.sub_crs_list[1].is_vertical
True
```